# How can I disable a specific javascript function in my base theme?

Tags: javascript

There is a single javascript function in my base theme that I want to disable and I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

I have read the documentation on how to disable a whole file with `libraries-override`, but I am looking for a way to disable only a function in a file.

I tried adding a .js file to my sub-theme and setting the function to null, but that didn't work.

Is there a way to disable a single function like `toggleNav()`, which is defined in Olivero's *navigation.js* file?

Comment: Would you please specify which function you wish to disable?

Comment: @cilefen toggleNav in Olivero's navigation.js file

Comment: One way is to remove the event listener from elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener